# Pesquisa desenvolvida em AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

Estou completamente a "zero" em angularJS e preciso de melhorar as funcionalidades de pesquisa neste site https://www.nomalism.com/pesquisa#/ que não foi desenvolvido por mim.

Neste momento a pesquisa está "presa" à lista de características que pendem sobre a caixa de pesquisa, não permitindo uma pesquisa livre.

Código da Pesquisa

```
public function querySearch()
{
    $query = Product::selectAll()->groupBy('products.id');

    if (Input::get('purpose'))
    {
        $purpose_id = Input::get('purpose');
        $query->join('product_purpose', function($join) use($purpose_id)
        {
            $join->on('product_purpose.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                 ->where('purpose_id', '=', $purpose_id);
        });
    }

    if (Input::get('category'))
    {
        $query->where('category_id', Input::get('category'));
    }

    $available_filters = array_keys(Product::allFilters());
    foreach ($available_filters as $filter)
    {
        if (Input::has($filter))
        {
            switch ($filter)
            {
                case 'color' :

                    $colors = explode(',', Input::get('color'));
                    foreach ($colors as $i => $color)
                    {
                        $alias = "color_product_$i";
                        $query->join("color_product as $alias", function($join) use($color, $alias)
                                {
                                    $join->on("$alias.product_id", '=', 'products.id')
                                         ->where("$alias.color_id", '=', $color);
                                });
                    }

                    break;

                case 'pattern' :

                    $patterns = explode(',', Input::get('pattern'));
                    foreach ($patterns as $i => $pattern)
                    {
                        $alias = "pattern_product_$i";
                        $query->join("pattern_product as $alias", function($join) use($pattern, $alias)
                                {
                                    $join->on("$alias.product_id", '=', 'products.id')
                                         ->where("$alias.pattern_id", '=', $pattern);
                                });
                    }

                    break;

                case 'width' :

                    $widths = array_map(function($width)
                        {
                            return (string)bcdiv($width, 100, 2);

                        }, explode(',', Input::get('width')));

                    $first_width = array_shift($widths);
                    $query->where(function($query) use($first_width, $widths)
                    {
                        $query->where('dimension_x', $first_width);
                        foreach ($widths as $width)
                        {
                            $query->orWhere('dimension_x', $width);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case 'attribute' :

                    $attributes = explode(',', Input::get('attribute'));
                    foreach ($attributes as $i => $attribute)
                    {
                        $alias = "attribute_product_$i";
                        $query->join("attribute_product as $alias", function($join) use($attribute, $alias)
                                {
                                    $join->on("$alias.product_id", '=', 'products.id')
                                         ->where("$alias.attribute_id", '=', $attribute);
                                });
                    }

                    break;

                case 'keyword' :

                    $keywords = explode(',', Input::get('keyword'));
                    foreach ($keywords as $i => $keyword)
                    {
                        $alias = "keyword_product_$i";
                        $query->join("keyword_product as $alias", function($join) use($keyword, $alias)
                                {
                                    $join->on("$alias.product_id", '=', 'products.id')
                                         ->where("$alias.keyword_id", '=', $keyword);
                                });
                    }

                    break;

                case 'name' :

                    $names = explode(',', Input::get('name'));
                    $first_name = array_shift($names);
                    $query->where(function($query) use($first_name, $names)
                    {
                        $query->where('name', $first_name);
                        foreach ($names as $name)
                        {
                            $query->orWhere('name', $name);
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case 'ref' :

                    $refs = explode(',', Input::get('ref'));
                    $first_ref = array_shift($refs);
                    $query->where(function($query) use($first_ref, $refs)
                    {
                        $query->where('ref', $first_ref);
                        foreach ($refs as $ref)
                        {
                            $query->orWhere('ref', $ref);
                        }
                    });

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Price filter
    if (Input::has('min'))
    {
        $query->where('price_in_cents', '>=', Input::get('min')*100);
    }
    if (Input::has('max'))
    {
        $query->where('price_in_cents', '<=', Input::get('max')*100);
    }

    if (Input::get('sales'))
    {
        $query->whereOnSale();
    }

    $items = $query->where('active', true)
                   ->orderBy('updated_on_remote', 'desc')
                   ->orderBy('ref', 'asc')
                   ->paginate(Input::get('limit'));

    $items->setBaseUrl(url(Input::get('base_url')));

    return $items;
}

public function search()
{
    $items = $this->querySearch();

    Session::put('limit.search', Input::get('limit', 24));

    return View::make('partials.search-results', compact('items'));
}
```

Pretendo alterar para que a pesquisa seja livre (fulltext search), já que neste momento tenho um campo na tabela produtos com todas as palavras que realmente interessa que sejam pesquisáveis.

Comment: Acredito que o questionamento não ficou claro, eu abri o site mas não identifiquei que tipo de alteração você quer fazer. Creio que a consulta está mais ligada com a lógica executada em sua aplicação Angular do que com a tela em si.
Poderia tentar ser mais claro no objetivo ou talvez partilhar o código desta "consulta"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer uma pesquisa fulltext(por qualquer atributo relacionado a um objeto que esteja e tela).

Com angular isso é bem simples, nesse exemplo também existe a possibilidade de ordenação

```js
function ShoppingCartCtrl($scope)  {
    
        $scope.items = [
   {Name: "Soap", Price: "25", Quantity: "10"},
   {Name: "Shaving cream", Price: "50", Quantity: "15"},
   {Name: "Shampoo", Price: "100", Quantity: "5"}
  ];
   
  $scope.mySortFunction = function(item) {
   if(isNaN(item[$scope.sortExpression]))
    return item[$scope.sortExpression];
   return parseInt(item[$scope.sortExpression]);
  }
}
```

```css
.bold { font-weight:bold; }

table td{
    padding: 10px;
}

table th{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <span class="bold">Demonstrating filtering and sorting using Angular JS</span>
    <br /><br />
        <div ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">        
            <div>Sort by: 
            <select ng-model="sortExpression">
     <option value="Name">Name</option>
     <option value="Price">Price</option>
     <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>
    </select>
            </div>
   <br />
   <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>By Any: </td>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.$" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>By Name: </td>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>By Price: </td>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Price" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>By Quantity: </td>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
            <br />
            <table border="1">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:mySortFunction | filter:search">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <br />
</div>
</div>
```

Agora você precisa analisar quais são as reais necessidade de pesquisa. Quanto mais informação for necessária mais essa busca vai demorar.